# Photo registered in the database is repeated in my system when listing

Tags: arrays, image, jsp, arraylist, methods

I have 2 methods that take it out of a video to be able to list images from the database to my ssitea in a jsp, what happens is that my system lists the images of a single person and they are repeated, when it should be showing the photo of each

method to list

```
public ArrayList<CitaVO> listarCitas(String cliente_idCliente) {

        CitaVO citVO = null;
        conexion = this.obtenerConexion();
        ArrayList<CitaVO> listaCitas = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            sql = "SELECT * FROM vwcitasactivas WHERE cliente_idCliente=?";
            puente = conexion.prepareStatement(sql);
            puente.setString(1, cliente_idCliente);
            mensajero = puente.executeQuery();

            while (mensajero.next()) {
                citVO = new CitaVO(mensajero.getString(1),
                        mensajero.getString(2), mensajero.getBinaryStream(3),
                        mensajero.getString(4), mensajero.getString(5),
                        mensajero.getString(6), mensajero.getString(7),
                        mensajero.getString(8), mensajero.getString(9),
                        mensajero.getString(10), mensajero.getString(11),
                        mensajero.getString(12),cliente_idCliente);
                listaCitas.add(citVO);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(ProAgendaDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        return listaCitas;
    }
```

method to list images

```
public void listarImg(String cliente_idCliente,HttpServletResponse response){
             InputStream inputStream= null;
             OutputStream outputStream=null;
             BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream=null;
             BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream=null;
             response.setContentType("image/*");
        try {
            conexion = this.obtenerConexion();
             sql = "SELECT * FROM vwcitasactivas WHERE cliente_idCliente=?";
             outputStream=response.getOutputStream();
             puente = conexion.prepareStatement(sql);
            puente.setString(1, cliente_idCliente);
             mensajero = puente.executeQuery();
            if (mensajero.next()) {
                inputStream=(mensajero.getBinaryStream(3));
            }
            bufferedInputStream=new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
            bufferedOutputStream=new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
            int i=0;
            while((i=bufferedInputStream.read())!=-1){
                bufferedOutputStream.write(i);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(CitaDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CitaDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                Conexion conexBd = new Conexion();
                conexBd.cerrarConexion();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(CitaDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            }
        }
        
    }
```

my jsp code

```
 <%
<%
CitaVO citVO = new CitaVO();
CitaDAO citDAO = new CitaDAO();
ArrayList<CitaVO> listaCitas = citDAO.listarCitas(idCliente);
for (int i = 0; i < listaCitas.size(); i++) {
    citVO = listaCitas.get(i);

%>
<tr>
<td>
    <div class="round-img">
        <a href=""><img src="ImagenControlador?idCliente=<%=idCliente%>" alt="" width="50px" height="50px" ></a>
    </div>
</td>
<td><%=citVO.getUsuNombre()%> <%=citVO.getUsuApellido()%></td>
<td><%=citVO.getUsuCiudad()%></td>
<td><%=citVO.getCitFecha()%></td>
<td><%=citVO.getProDia()%></td>
<td><%=citVO.getCitDireccion()%></td>
<td><%=citVO.getCitHoraInicio()%></td>
<td><%=citVO.getCitHoraFin()%></td>
<td <%=citVO.getCitEstado()%>><span class="badge badge-primary">Activa</span></td>
<td  style="text-align: center">
    <span><a href="Cita?opcion=6&textId=<%=citVO.getIdCita()%>&textEstado=<%=citVO.getCitEstado()%>"><i class="ti-eye color-default" style="font-size: 18px"></i></a> </span>
    <span><a href="Cita?opcion=7&textId=<%=citVO.getIdCita()%>"><i class="ti-pencil-alt color-success" style="font-size: 18px"></i></a></span>
    <span><a href="Cita?opcion=3&textId=<%=citVO.getIdCita()%>&textEstado=<%=citVO.getCitEstado()%>" class="btn sweet-confirm" onclick="return cancelarCita(event)"><i class="ti-trash color-danger" style="font-size: 18px"></i> </a></span>
</td>
</tr>
<%}%
```

these are my two methods to list the information and images and my jsp code where I list everything and the next result is the following
[image]

As you can see, I list the same image when the last person should have a totally different photo, I don't know why this happens, I answer any questions in the comments

Comment: Hi, what `idCliente` has in it ? Are you changing its value anywhere ? and in your  code you have pass same `idCliente` to your backend to load image i think it has same value everytime .

Comment: I use the client id to list the people who have the same id in this case they are 2 people, the first two in the photo and the last

Comment: Yup that's the issue when you call your code only first entry with that `id` is fetch so only one photo is retrieved from backend . You should use something else that is unique to all records to retrieve images.

Comment: an example please

Comment: i mean to say instead of passing `id` pass another column which is unique to all records .

Comment: I already understood you and indeed it worked for me, thank you very much